# V-select in Datatable onchange cannot pass the value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is that possible to pass the item value and select value when changing the v-select value?

```
<template #item.progress="{ item }">
    <div>
        <v-select
            :items="list"
            label="status"
            :model="item.progress"
            @change="changeProgress(item)"
        ></v-select>
    </div>
</template>

methods: {
    changeProgress(item) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.val);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `:model` to `v-model=`, which is the syntax for Vue's built-in default model binding:

```html
v-model="item.progress"
```

Now the `item.progress` property will be automatically updated when the selection is changed.  If you still need to do something more in the `change` handler, you can pass both by passing the `$event` variable (which will hold the selected value) along with the item:

```html
@change="changeProgress($event, item)"
```

Your handler should then have a structure like:

```js
methods: {
  changeProgress(selected, item) {
    console.log(selected, item);
  }
}
```